# Finding time overlaps using SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, sqlite

I have a single table consisting of a series of time data such as the following:

```
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
| person | start              | end                 |
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
| a      |2014-12-04 13:00:00 | 2014-12-04 14:00:00 |
| a      |2014-12-04 13:30:00 | 2014-12-04 14:30:00 |
| b      |2014-12-04 13:00:00 | 2014-12-04 14:00:00 |
| b      |2014-12-04 13:30:00 | 2014-12-04 14:30:00 |
| b      |2014-12-04 14:00:00 | 2014-12-04 15:00:00 |
| a      |2014-12-04 19:00:00 | 2014-12-04 20:00:00 |
| a      |2014-12-04 19:30:00 | 2014-12-04 20:30:00 |
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I want to find time overlaps and output the following:

```
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
| person | start              | end                 |
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
| a      |2014-12-04 13:00:00 | 2014-12-04 14:30:00 |
| b      |2014-12-04 13:00:00 | 2014-12-04 15:00:00 |
| a      |2014-12-04 19:00:00 | 2014-12-04 20:30:00 |
+--------+--------------------+---------------------+
```

So I'm looking for a query to find instances where time intervals overlap, I want to see the person who the time interval relates to and the earliest time slot and the latest time slot.

Tricky to explain but I hope you get the jist!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's quite tricky but possible if you have a recent version of sqlite that support `WITH RECURSIVE` (doesn't work on sqlfiddle.com):

```
create table intervals (
  person text,
  start timestamp,
  end timestamp
);

insert into intervals values ('a', '2014-12-04 13:00:00', '2014-12-04 14:00:00');
insert into intervals values ('a', '2014-12-04 13:30:00', '2014-12-04 14:30:00');
insert into intervals values ('b', '2014-12-04 13:00:00', '2014-12-04 14:00:00');
insert into intervals values ('b', '2014-12-04 13:30:00', '2014-12-04 14:30:00');
insert into intervals values ('b', '2014-12-04 14:00:00', '2014-12-04 15:00:00');
insert into intervals values ('a', '2014-12-04 19:00:00', '2014-12-04 20:00:00');
insert into intervals values ('a', '2014-12-04 19:30:00', '2014-12-04 20:30:00');

WITH RECURSIVE
 merged_intervals(person, start, end) AS (
    select person, start, end
    from intervals

    where not exists (
        select * from intervals i2 
        where i1.person=i2.person
        and (i2.start<i1.start and i2.end>=i1.start)
    )

 UNION ALL
    select i1.person, i1.start, i2.end
    from merged_intervals i1, intervals i2 
    where i1.start<=i2.start and i1.end>i2.start and i1.end<i2.end
    and i1.person=i2.person
)
select * from merged_intervals i1
where not exists (
    select * from merged_intervals i2 
    where i1.person=i2.person
    and (
        (i2.start<i1.start and i2.end>i1.start)
        or
        (i2.end>i1.end and i2.start<i1.end)
        )
    )
order by start, person
;
```

Comment: That seems to work (although I can't claim to understand it all!). I was running SQLite version 3.7.16.2 but had to upgrade to the latest version to allow me to do it. If anyone is interested, support for the WITH clause was added in [SQLite 3.8.3](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_3.html)

Comment: I've hit a problem. This worked great on the sample data but I get the following message when I try and run it on my actual database (which has a little over 5500 rows in it):
    database or disk is full
The disk is not full by the way! There is 20GB free on it.
Any ideas?

Comment: I've added a where clause that can improve performances, tell me if it solves your pb (and if it still works :-)